# A UI component becomes null in the handler of the UI thread

Tags: android, android-widget

In my Android application, I have UI thread and a child thread. The child thread sends messages to the UI thread that need to be printed on a TextView. I initialize the TextView in the UI thread, I spawn the child thread, the child thread sends messages to the UI thread but the UI thread fails in handleMessage(). After debugging, I have found that the TextView is null in the HandleMessage(). Below I show the code of the UI and child threads. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**In the UI thread:**

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public TextView mMatchesText;
    public Handler mHandler;  
    private ServerConnection conn;
    private String mProfile;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mMatchesText = (TextView) Example.this.findViewById(R.id.matches);
        mMatchesText.setText("Matches:\n");     /*this text appears when I run the app*/


    Example.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(mMatchesText == null)
                Log.e("MY APP", "Before creating thread: mMatchesText is null");
            else
                Log.e("MY APP", "Before creating thread: mMatchesText is not null");    

            mProfile = FileReader.readFileAsString(getApplicationContext(), "profile.txt"));
            conn = new ServerConnection(mProfile);

            if(mMatchesText == null)
                Log.e("MY APP", "After creating thread: mMatchesText is null");
            else
                Log.e("MY APP", "After creating thread: mMatchesText is not null");
        }
    });
}        

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                 Log.e("MY APP", "In handler: Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                 if(mMatchesText == null)
                     Log.e("MY APP", "In handler: mMatchesText is null");
                 else
                     Log.e("MY APP", "In handler: mMatchesText is not null");

                Log.e("MY APP", "In handler: " + (String)msg.obj);
                mMatchesText.setText((String)msg.obj);
            }
};
```

**Note that the TextView is not null before and after spawning the child thread. In the Handler, the message is received correctly but the TextView is null even though it is the UI thread that's executing the handler.**

**In the child thread:**

```
public class ServerConnection extends Example implements Runnable
{
    /* constructor */
    public ServerConnection()
    {
       runner = new Thread(this);
       runner.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String fromServer;

        /** Establish connection to the server */

        /** Wait for messages from the server */
        while((fromServer = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Message toMain = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            toMain.obj = fromServer;
            mHandler.sendMessage(toMain);   
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me.